# How can I make my NFT visible in the NEAR wallet (AssemblyScript)?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to implement my own NFT-contract, [following this tutorial on NEAR](https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/contracts/nfts/minting), and the [Non-Fungible Token (NEP-171) specifications](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html#nft-interface). The tutorial is in `Rust`, but I'm trying to do something similar with `AssemblyScript`. I thought if I implemented the methods with the correct names and signature, it would be possible for the NEAR wallet to call the respective methods (e.g. `nft_tokens_for_owner`) on my NFT-contract. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something, or if I have the wrong understanding on how it's suppose to work.

I have minted one NFT-token, using the `nft_mint` method in my contract, using my own testnet account. The transaction can be found [here](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/5HKBByzHR7PckmAqLpZdtmuwuL9rtJJ3pSzDETFSWMSs). However, the NFT is not displayed in the "Collectibles" tab in my testnet wallet.

My contract (index.ts) looks like this:

```as
import { PersistentMap } from 'near-sdk-as';
import { Token, TokenMetadata } from './reit-token';

@nearBindgen
class NFTContractMetadata {
  spec: string; // required, essentially a version like "nft-1.0.0"
  name: string; // required, ex. "Mochi Rising — Digital Edition" or "Metaverse 3"
  symbol: string; // required, ex. "MOCHI"
  icon: string | null; // Data URL
  base_uri: string | null; // Centralized gateway known to have reliable access to decentralized storage assets referenced by `reference` or `media` URLs
  reference: string | null; // URL to a JSON file with more info
  reference_hash: string | null; // Base64-encoded sha256 hash of JSON from reference field. Required if `reference` is included.
}

@nearBindgen
export class Contract {
  //keeps track of the metadata for the contract
  metadata: NFTContractMetadata = {
    spec: 'reit-token-0.0.0',
    name: 'Reit Token',
    symbol: 'REIT',
    icon: null,
    base_uri: null,
    reference: null,
    reference_hash: null,
  };

  //contract owner
  owner_id: string; // Not sure if this is relevant for the contract itself

  //keeps track of all the token IDs for a given account
  tokens_per_owner: PersistentMap<string, Array<string>> = new PersistentMap<
    string,
    Array<string>
  >('tokens_pr_owner');

  //keeps track of the token struct for a given token ID
  tokens_by_id: PersistentMap<string, Token> = new PersistentMap<string, Token>(
    'tokens_by_id'
  );

  //keeps track of the token metadata for a given token ID
  token_metadata_by_id: PersistentMap<string, TokenMetadata> =
    new PersistentMap<string, TokenMetadata>('token_metadata_by_id');

  nft_tokens_for_owner(account_id: string): Array<Token> {
    const tokenIds: string[] = this.tokens_per_owner.getSome(account_id);

    const tokens: Array<Token> = new Array<Token>();
    for (let i = 0; i < tokenIds.length; ++i) {
      const token: Token = this.tokens_by_id.getSome(tokenIds[i]);
      tokens.push(token);
    }
    return tokens;
  }

  nft_mint(
    token_id: string,
    metadata: TokenMetadata,
    receiver_id: string
  ): void {
    // assert(
    //   this.tokens_by_id.contains(token_id),
    //   'ID is already taken, create new ID'
    // );
    const token = new Token(token_id, metadata, receiver_id);
    const tokens: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
    tokens.push(token_id);
    this.tokens_per_owner.set(receiver_id, tokens);
    this.tokens_by_id.set(token_id, token);
    this.token_metadata_by_id.set(token_id, token.metadata);
  }
```

Inside reit-token.ts

```as
import { ContractPromise } from 'near-sdk-as';
// implementation based on NEP-171
// https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html

@nearBindgen
export class TokenMetadata {
  title: string; // ex. "Arch Nemesis: Mail Carrier" or "Parcel #5055"
  description: string; // free-form description
  media: string; // URL to associated media, preferably to decentralized, content-addressed storage
  media_hash: string; // Base64-encoded sha256 hash of content referenced by the `media` field. Required if `media` is included.
  copies: number; // number of copies of this set of metadata in existence when token was minted.
  issued_at: number; // When token was issued or minted, Unix epoch in milliseconds
  expires_at: number; // When token expires, Unix epoch in milliseconds
  starts_at: number; // When token starts being valid, Unix epoch in milliseconds
  updated_at: number; // When token was last updated, Unix epoch in milliseconds
  extra: string; // anything extra the NFT wants to store on-chain. Can be stringified JSON.
  reference: string; // URL to an off-chain JSON file with more info.
  reference_hash: string; // Base64-encoded sha256 hash of JSON from reference field. Required if `reference` is included.
}

@nearBindgen
export class Token {
  id: string;
  owner_id: string;
  metadata: TokenMetadata;
  constructor(token_id: string, metadata: TokenMetadata, receiver_id: string) {
    this.id = token_id;
    this.metadata = metadata;
    this.owner_id = receiver_id;
  }
}

@nearBindgen
export class ReitToken {
  token: Token;

  constructor(token_id: string, metadata: TokenMetadata, receiver_id: string) {
    this.token = { id: token_id, metadata: metadata, owner_id: receiver_id };
  }
  // --- view methods --- //

  nft_token(): Token {
    return this.token;
  }

  // --- change methods --- //

  nft_transfer(
    receiver_id: string,
    token_id: string,
    approval_id: number,
    memo: string
  ): void {
    // assert(false, 'nft_transfer not implemented');
  }

  nft_transfer_call(
    receiver_id: string,
    token_id: string,
    approval_id: number,
    memo: string,
    msg: string
  ): ContractPromise {
    // assert(false, 'nft_transfer_call not implemented');
    return ContractPromise.create('', '', {}, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking around, I was pointed to two different GitHub repositories that implemented an NFT-token smart contract in AssemblyScript.

- https://github.com/dOrgTech/proof-of-attendance
- https://github.com/vgrichina/humanguild-nft/tree/lisbon

After going through those repositories, I noticed that my contract wasn't that far off to be able to display my NFT-tokens in the wallet. I had to implement one more function, `nft_metadata()`.

I did have metadata in my contract, but as a variable, `metadata`. Returning the same metadata in `nft_metadata()` seemed to do the trick

```as
@nearBindgen
class NFTContractMetadata {
  constructor(
    public spec: string = 'reit-token-0.0.0', // required, essentially a version like "nft-1.0.0"
    public name: string = 'Reit Token', // required, ex. "Mochi Rising — Digital Edition" or "Metaverse 3"
    public symbol: string = 'REIT', // required, ex. "MOCHI"
    public icon: string = '', // Data URL
    public base_uri: string = '', // Centralized gateway known to have reliable access to decentralized storage assets referenced by `reference` or `media` URLs
    public reference: string = '', // URL to a JSON file with more info
    public reference_hash: string = '' // Base64-encoded sha256 hash of JSON from reference field. Required if `reference` is included.
  ) {}
}

@nearBindgen
export class Contract {
// ...

  nft_metadata(): NFTContractMetadata {
    return new NFTContractMetadata();
  }

// ...
}
```

I did override my existing NFT with a new one ([transaction found here](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/G9HYJauGWaF2mNxyeyTDpTBtosZiZ29ABBeBABzAVLWH)) while testing, and here it is, visible in the NEAR testnet wallet

[image]